# 'str' object has no attribute 'dropna'

Tags: python, pandas, google-colaboratory

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn import linear_model 
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder 

from google.colab import files
df = files.upload()
df='Dataset.csv'
df=df.dropna()
```

---

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 df=df.dropna()

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'dropna'

Comment: `df.dropna()` expects df to be a pandas dataframe. The second last line of your code sets df to a string, hence the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not loading the file as a dataframe, you just assign the file name of `df`. Use instead -

```
df = pd.read_csv('Dataset.csv')
df = df.dropna()
```