# Python folium problem with removing NAN from the popup

Tags: python, pandas, folium

I have the excel list with some blanks columns. I would like to remove NAN, but I don't know how.

I used the `dropna()` function, but didn't work in my case.

```
 df = pd.read_csv("work2.csv")

 for i,row in df.iterrows():
lat = df.at[i, 'lat']
lng = df.at[i, 'lng']
sp = df.at[i, 'sp']
stat = df.at[i,'title']
skill = df.at[i,'skillset']
skill2 = df.at[i,'skillset2']
#skill3 = df.at[i(float).notna(), 'skillset3']
skill4 = df.at[i,'skillset4']
```

but I get the TypeError

Is there any way of removing the NaN from the Python folium popup which uses data manipulated by pandas?

The solution proposed here:

['str' object has no attribute 'dropna'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61074332/str-object-has-no-attribute-dropna)

leads to the situation where I have only one input visible.

[image]

Comment: Please provide a complete example with data (as text not an image) and expected result which makes your requirement clear.

Comment: Your intention is not clear without you showing any data. `i` is the index of the row (hence an integer 0... unless you have defined an alternative index). So what is the intention with the statement `#skill3 = df.at[i(float).notna(), 'skillset3']` and specifically with `i(float).notna()`

Comment: I've added an image already. I want to have these blank cells omitted but I don't know how to do it

Comment: What do you mean by remove blank cells? Remove the whole row from the Pandas DataFrame or what? And why is the first element of skillset3 column not removed as it is also blank/NaN. Responding to questions is much easier if you provide a [mre] as the SO guidelines recommend,

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the *skills* are on the rightmost side of your `df`, you could use [`pd.notna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.notna.html) this way :

```
for lat, lng, sp, stat, *skillsets in df.to_numpy():
    html = "<ul>"
    for skill in skillsets:
        if pd.notna(skill):
            html += f"<li>{skill}</li>"
    html += "</ul>"

    iframe = folium.IFrame(html) # to be adjusted if needed
    popup = folium.Popup(iframe, min_width=300, max_width=300)

    _ = folium.Marker([lat, lng], popup=popup).add_to(m) # or whatever
```